# How to run ALL tests in a solution using command line vstest.console.exe?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, continuous-integration

What is the best way to run all tests in a solution using command line vstest.console.exe?

Answer (score 0):

you could try this, which talks about how to use VSTest exe to run the tests in the build.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/ms253138.aspx#Runner_VS

Comment: That's only good for team projects. My project isn't setup for a team.

Comment: The link is broken